# why cant i use model inside modal

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog

i want to show a form inside a blade view in laravel, i have my route and my controller, but if i try to show my form inside a modal it shows an empty modal

```html
<div>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="create" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">add new shipment</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    @section('main-content')
                                        <div class="container">
                                            @yield('/shipment/create')
                                        </div>
                                    @endsection
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

any idea why? or is it simply not possible the way i'm trying to do it?

Comment: You should check if the content you're trying to display is actually not empty.

Comment: Your app has no concept of a "modal." The template outputs what it's told, where it's told to. It's all HTML. Presumably you've got a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to include **create** file not **yield** it as a section. If so, then change:

```
@yield('/shipment/create')
```

to:

```
@include('shipment/create')
```

Also, be sure to write the right path for your form file.

Comment: thanks, i tried your solution and it triggers a lot of errors,i guess i'll try looking deeper into modals, maybe i understood wrongly what they are and do.